# Configure Iptables to allow a PHP-app accessing a port-nr

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, security, php

I have a php-application which connects to another app called Solr (database search engine).
I can via this php app add/remove documents (records) from the Solr index.

However, the Solr security is low, and anybody with the right port nr can access Solr and remove documents (records).

I wonder, is it possible to ONLY allow my own php-app to have access to Solr somehow?
Prefferably via Iptables. I am thinking I can only allow my own servers IP to that port, and it would solve my problem, because PHP is a server-side code. But I am not sure.

About the Php-app: 
The website is a classifieds website, and when users wants to add or remove classifieds, they do so through a php app, which is this one.
The app has a function which connects to solr and updates the database (index).

I appreciate detailed answers...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that with iptables. Your best bet is using something in solr

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrSecurity

Answer (score 0):

No you can't control what application connects to a specific port, even on the local machine (you can do this with file permissions and Unix domain sockets - but not across a network).

Yes, you should restrict network access onthe SOLR port to a specific white-list. And if there are machines connecting from outside the local LAN, consider using IPSEC or a VPN and restricting access to that.

Alternatively, for remote access you might consider disallowing ALL access to the SOLR port, except for the localhost then running [stunnel](http://www.stunnel.org/) at both ends and require client certificate validation - and run your own snake oil CA if required.

HTH

C.